# Why is marking a flag as Invalid from /tools not a binding choice even when a Diamond User is marking it as Invalid?

Tags: support, flags, flag-queue

Generally, most actions taken by Stack Exchange Diamond Moderators are binding. However yesterday I discovered that this is not true in this single case.

Diamond Moderators have access to flagged posts from the Moderator queue as well as the `/tools` queue. While going through the `/tools` queue, there's an option to deem a flag as invalid - however this action is not binding - the flagged post still remains in the queue after marking it as invalid.

So why is this not a binding action? All other flags/action/votes such as spam/offensive, close votes done by a ♦ are binding, so I'm trying to understand why this is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/tools` is not designed with moderators in mind, and the whole `invalid flag` thing makes no sense in the context of a moderator.

The intention is for it to assist moderators in making decisions.

The `invalid flag` has special handling that bypasses the area where mods votes are binding. I do not see any real reason to fix this cause as a moderator you really should stay away from the `/tools/flagged` area, it offers nothing you can not achieve in the mod panel.

Answer (score 6):

All binding actions operate on the system of "If a ♦ does it, it counts as sufficient quantity to cause an action". In this case, this cannot be done for marking a flag as invalid from `/tools`.

Flags for "invalid flag" *do nothing* when they accumulate in quantity. They are like flagging a post as "not an answer" - it's just a moderator flag that indicates a suggestion of attention. Mechanically, it causes the flag resolution to be "disputed" rather than valid/invalid, but this occurs regardless of quantity. It is otherwise exactly in behavior like any other *actual*<sup>†</sup> moderator attention flag - their lack of binding nature is because there is nothing for a moderator attention flag to have a threshold for such a binding action to apply to.

<sub><sup>†</sup>Take into account that "does not belong here" is no longer a moderator attention flag when it auto-converts to a close vote, and that spam/offensive are not moderator attention flags, in case you try to see a discrepancy.</sub>